# Encountering conditional if else

Tags: r

I got a data frame (test) with a matrix of 4 x 2. I intended to use ifelse function to fix the dataset. Lines of code as below:

```
  test <- data.frame(cbind(c(4,-5,-6,1),c("1","-3","4","-3")),stringsAsFactors = F)
  test$X1 <- as.numeric(test$X1)
  test$X2 <- as.numeric(test$X2)
  test$X2 <- ifelse(test$X1<0 & test$X2>0, test$X2, test$X2*-1)
```

How do we write a code which apply the vice versa condition which means that if X1 < 0 & X2 > 0, then make X2 < 0, which apply the same on X1 (vice versa on the same logic)

The expected output is:

```
X1 <- 4 -5 -6 -1
X2 <- 1 -3 -4 -3
```

Would appreciate on any ideas.

Comment: `test$X1 < 0 && test$X2 > 0` ... you need two `&&`

Comment: @NelsonGon, the idea was, the output of X2 should refer to X1 data whenever if X1 < 0 & X2 > 0, then X2 will output negative. Next, X1 will read through X2 data which the aim is the same like the first one.

Comment: Sorry, I find it quite hard to understand but glad to see that Ronak figured it out.

Comment: Why not just do: `test %>% 
  mutate(X2 = ifelse(X1 <0 & X2>0, -X2, X2))` with `dplyr` and the same for X1? Not sure what transformation you're doing to X1? Could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could achieve the desired result as follows using `dplyr`(assuming I understood the logic (**which means that if X1 < 0 & X2 > 0, then make X2 < 0, which apply the same on X1 (vice versa on the same logic**) well):

```
 test %>% 
       mutate(X2 = ifelse(X1 <0 & X2>0, -X2, X2),
              X1 = ifelse(X2<0 & X1>0, -X1,X1))
  X1 X2
1  4  1
2 -5 -3
3 -6 -4
4 -1 -3
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks simpler and precise. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
test$X2 <- with(test, X2 * c(1, -1)[(X1 < 0 & X2 > 0) + 1])
test$X1 <- with(test, X1 * c(1, -1)[(X1 > 0 & X2 < 0) + 1])
test
#  X1 X2
#1  4  1
#2 -5 -3
#3 -6 -4
#4 -1 -3
```

To explain, let's take the first case.

The condition returns a logical vector

```
with(test, X1 < 0 & X2 > 0)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

By adding `+ 1` we convert it to numerical index where `FALSE` becomes 1 and `TRUE` becomes 2

```
with(test, X1 < 0 & X2 > 0) + 1
#[1] 1 1 2 1
```

We use this index to subset `c(1, -1)`

```
c(1, -1)[with(test, X1 < 0 & X2 > 0) + 1]
#[1]  1  1 -1  1
```

which is then multiplied to `X2`

```
with(test, X2 * c(1, -1)[(X1 < 0 & X2 > 0) + 1])
#[1]  1 -3 -4 -3
```

Comment: could you please elaborate more why do we have to add 1 at the end of the code?

Comment: @JonSirNo I added some explanation, hopefully it clears it.

Comment: ahh see. Thanks for the great idea and insight!